# disable <a> tag for a period of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

To simplify my problem, I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vswcp09m/)

When I click on "Click me" it displays a box, but when i click on it twice 
at the same time, it displays two boxes at the same time, and for my case it should not be possible. The second box should be able to be displayed only if the first box is completly displayed and the user click again on 'Click me'.

How can I achieve that ?

```js
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $div = $('<div>', {
    "class": "newDiv"
  });

  $('#container').append($div);
  $div.show('clip', 3000);
});
```

```css
#clickme {
  cursor: pointer
}

.newDiv {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 5px;
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<a id="clickme">Click me</a>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the cleanest solution is to bind and unbind your click handler. No need to use a flag or a timeout.

```
function clickHandler() {
  $div = $('<div>', {
    "class": "newDiv"
  });
  $('#container').append($div);

  // Unbind click handler until animation is completed
  $("#clickme").off("click", clickHandler);

  // Begin animation
  $div.show('clip', 3000, function() {
    // Animation completed. Bind click handler.
    $("#clickme").on("click", clickHandler);
  });
}

// Initial bind of click handler
$("#clickme").on("click", clickHandler);
```

Here's [a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/vswcp09m/5/).

Comment: I'll go with @Satpal solution because it is easy to implement for my case but I think your solution should be the cleanest and the right solution.

Answer (score 7):

A simple solution is to use a flag, to check the state whether action can be performed.

Here `complete` callback of [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/#show-duration-complete) is used to reset the flag once effect is complete.

```js
var disable = false;
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  var elem = $(this);
  if (disable == false) {
    disable = !disable;
    elem.toggleClass('none', disable);
    $div = $('<div>', {
      "class": "newDiv"
    });

    $('#container').append($div);
    $div.show('clip', 3000, function() {
      disable = !disable;
      elem.toggleClass('none', disable);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#clickme {
  cursor: pointer
}

#clickme.none {
  cursor: none
}

.newDiv {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 5px;
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<a id="clickme">Click me</a>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: argh you were faster! :D

Comment: Add cursor: default while you can't click and then it would be perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the button for the time when the box is being drawn. Like this:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
   disabling the button for 3000 sec as the box takes 3000 sec to get rendered.
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(this).attr('disabled','disable');
  },3000);
  $(this).removeAttr('disabled');

  $div = $('<div>', {
    "class": "newDiv"
  });

  $('#container').append($div);
  $div.show('clip', 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to stop execution if the box is still being animated.
I am using the `complete` argument of jQuery.show method.

```
var inAnimation = false;
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  if(inAnimation)
      return;
  $div = $('<div>', {
    "class": "newDiv"
  });

  $('#container').append($div);
  inAnimation = true;
  $div.show('clip', 3000, function() {inAnimation = false;});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i always use callback after end of animation:

```
let open = true;
$('#clickme').click(function(){
if ( open ) {
    open = false;
  $div = $('<div>',{"class" : "newDiv"});
  $('#container').append($div);
  $div.show('clip',3000, function(){
    open = true;
  });
}
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vswcp09m/2/)

Answer (score -1):

If you want a simple solution for your problem you can place an if statement before the assignment of the $div variable:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
if($('.newDiv').length == 0){
    $div = $('<div>', {
        "class": "newDiv"
    });


    $('#container').append($div);
    $div.show('clip', 3000);
}
});

$('.newDiv').click(function() {
    $('.newDiv').destroy();
}
```